# check 2 unordered lists of images and add to the old list the new images

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have 2 unordered lists both containing images but list2 will have the same images as list1 but with additions.

I would like to check list2 image sources with list1 image sources and if there are image sources which missing from list1 I would like to add them.

Here is an example of the lists

```
 <ul class="list1">
     <li><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/></a></li>
  </ul>

<ul class="list2">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is a fiddle of what I think should be done but I'm not so sure now.
http://jsfiddle.net/pNtHQ/4/

something like check sources for both lists and the missing ones from list1 get added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways to approach this, here's mine:

```
$("ul.list2 li img").each(function () {
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src")
    var matched = $("ul.list1 li img[src='" + imgSrc + "']");
    if (!matched.length) {
        $("ul.list1").append("<li><a href='#'><img src='" + imgSrc + "'/></a></li>")
    }
});
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pNtHQ/5/)

Comment: Works! Thanks very much, one more question is it possible instead of appending the img, to move it? or clone it along with the link? thanks

Comment: @TaraIrvine: Sure. You can use `.remove()` to remove items from the dom. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pNtHQ/13/) for a demo.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -

```
$('.list1 img').each(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  if($('.list2').find('img[src="'+src+'"]').length === 0){
   $('.list2').append($(this).closest('li').clone());
  }
})
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/pNtHQ/7/

Comment: Sorry it's not working for me, basically I want to add to list 1 images from list2 only if they are originals not the duplicates, thanks for the speedy response

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done using the attribute contains selector.
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6aktY/1/

```
$("ul.list1 li img").each( function() {
    var url = $( this ).attr( 'src' );
    var search_results = $( 'ul.list2 li img[src*="' + url + '"]' );

    if( search_results.size() === 0 )
    {
        $( 'ul.list2' ).append( '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + url + '" /></a></li>' );
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I can't get this to work sorry, if images from list2 exist in list1 then they shouldn't be appended but the rest should

Comment: Did you check my jsfiddle example? It does exactly that. Here's the same example with a random image added to list2: http://jsfiddle.net/6aktY/3/ 

As you can see all images from list1 that do not exist in list2 are appended to list2.

Comment: Yes, sorry I needed it the other way round and was looking at it the other way. Is there any way for the append to copy the entire list item? The images are all wrapped in links to different sources. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. So just to be clear you want list1 to be a copy of list2 but with additional images?

Comment: In that case I think this is what you're looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/6aktY/7/